# Enable/Disable SubmenuItems on Mdi Parent form in C# using Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, toolstripmenu

on Mdi parent form i am calling my child forms using menu items. on Child form Load my Menu item should be disabled on child form closed it will again Enabled.., i try FormClosing event handler i get the answer..,

```
  private void btnMn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Forms.Cnblfrm cnbfrm = new Cnsmblfrm();
        cnsmbfrm.MdiParent = this;
        cnsmbfrm.Text = btnMn1.Text;
        cnsmbfrm.Show();
        this.btnMn1.Enabled = false;
        cnbfrm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(cnsmbfrm_FormClosed);
    }

    void cnbfrm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnMn1.Enabled = true;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

by using the above code i am getting the answer but i have morethan 20 ChildForms. By using this method My coding is increasing...., there is any method instead of this....,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right: you have 20 buttons where every button opens a specific form, right?

If so, you can set the tag-property of each button to the form it opens. then you have to iterate through all buttons and set the click-event. All buttons have the same click-event. (let's call it btn_click)

the code of btn_click can look like:

```
private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button button = sender as Button;
   if(button == null)
      return;
   Form form = button.Tag as Form;
   if(form == null)
      return;
   form.MdiParent = this;
   form.Text = button.Text;
   form.Show();
   button.Enabled = false;
   form.Tag = button;
   form.FormClosed += FormClosed;
}

private void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   Form form = sender as Form;
   if(form == null)
      return;
   Button button = form.Tag as Button;
   if(button == null)
      return;
   button.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: How can i set the Tag for every form

Comment: I think this part you have to do manualy. So assign every form to the button in the constructor

Comment: where to i assign a tag in mdiparent form or in the Forms

Comment: In the form which contains the buttons for the other forms. I think this is your midparent-form

Comment: yes this is mdiparent form.from mdiparent form i want to access child forms